# Dynamic add PanoramaItems based on data and/or layout type

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

The idea is to create a panorama page with content from some server. Each PanoramaItem shows a container object from the server. The container object defines the type of data and its layout. Let's say I have 2 or 3 types of data and each data type has multiple layouts, think lists, grid or just some TextBlock.

In the end it looks something like this:

```
                              ------------------
                              | PanoramaPage 1 |
                              ------------------
                                     |
                                     |
          -------------------------------------------------------
          |                 |                 |                 |
          |                 |                 |                 |
    --------------    --------------    --------------    --------------
    |PanoramaItem|    |PanoramaItem|    |PanoramaItem|    |PanoramaItem|
    |DataType 2  |    |DataType 1  |    |DataType 10 |    |DataType 4  |
    |Layout   1  |    |Layout   2  |    |Layout   1  |    |Layout   4  |
    --------------    --------------    --------------    --------------
```

Remember each startup this could change to whatever the server likes to display.

All I see are examples or tutorials how to create some panorama or pivot with the items defined in the same xaml as the panorama page, not dynamic based upon some data and/or layout type.

Is it possible to separate each data/layout type to its own xaml and instantiate it on the fly supplied with its own ViewModel?

Since I'm quite new to the windows phone platform I'm not sure if I take the right approach.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Yes things can be created dynamically.

Two thoughts. The first thought is that anything that can be done in Xaml can be done in code, so any example you see is simply creating objects/instances from valid C# classes in the background via the Xaml parser; so you can do similar sans Xaml.

Secondly, don't get hung up on the page and navigation motif of most examples. I worked on a major Win Phone 8 published project where we only had one page with multiple hidden controls which would appear and give the impression of a navigated to page. That allowed for a shared ViewModel and all the data which goes along with it. In your case one VM to hold a list of subdata which could be shared across your panaramas.

I suggest you start out small and create dynamic panaramas without the data to get the flow working. Once that is going, then bring in the real data and deal with problems which will arise.

### Edit

Look into the [How to: Implement a CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405.aspx). That might provide the ability to show differing data as needed for your dynamic situation.